# Sails.js - How to render a partial from a controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, partial-views, sails.js

I have a partial view containing my login form. I would like to render it from an ajax call to my controller.

This is the sample where i would return my partial view:

```
postlogin: function (req,res) {

    var username = req.param('username');
    var password = req.param('password');

    User.find({
        username: username,
        password: password.salt()
    }).done(function(err, users){
        if(users.length == 1){
            // Here I want to return a partial view, not a view
            res.view('home/login', {message: 'Login success!'});
        }else{
            // Here I want to return a partial view, not a view
            res.view('home/login', {message: 'Login failed!'});
        }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ah! Found it!

If your view is a partial view, simply specify `layout: null`:

```
res.view('home/login', {message: 'Login failed!', layout: null});
```

Comment: Yep!  And if you want to disable the layout globally (doing things the more Express-3-ish partial-ish way) you can set `layout: false` in your `config/views.js` file.

Answer (score 5):

Bottom of the page: http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views

## What about using multiple layouts?

Express 3 removed native support for layouts. In Sails, we've managed to keep this around, but we don't officially support multiple layouts.
That said, at least in EJS, instead of indicating your custom layout with the layout local, you must use _layoutFile:

```
/**
 * HomeController
 */
module.exports = {

    index: function (req, res) {
        res.view({
            _layoutFile: '../layouts/other.ejs'
        });
    },

};
```

Sails v0.9.7